# How to determine validation warning details in SSIS VS 2005

Tags: validation, ssis

In my control flow window, I have a data flow task that has a validation warning icon on it.  The tool tip text displays a general message: "Validation Warnings Occurred".  When I double-click to view it in the data flow task window, none of the objects have a validation warning.

It is is difficult to find the warning in the error list window  because I have a over 30 connection managers that do not map to my TFS local path and it produces 2 notifications per un-mapped connection manager.

Is there another way to determine where or what this warning is referring to?

I am using VS 2005 Professional with SSIS version 9.00.05000.00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those warnings sometimes hang around after the issue has been resolved.  Try closing and re-opening the package.

Also you can execute the package and review the Output window.